# add header to a big csv file >5GB

Tags: awk, sed

i have a big **csv** file (**5gb**) with **300 columns**, and i want to add a simple header via the commande line :

```
row-0;row1;row2 ... row299
```

i used sed (without a loop) :

```
sed -i 1i'row-0;row-1;row-2 .... ; row-299' file.csv
```

Is there a better/clean way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what this has to do with Linux/Unix.

Comment: i used sed to do this : `sed -i 1i'row-0;row-1;row-2 .... ; row-299' file.csv` , is there a better/clean way to do this ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller check the update

Comment: What about having your header in foo.csv then simply cat yourcsv >> foo.csv ?

Comment: by the way, both "300 columns" and "5GB" say, CSV is the wrong format

Comment: @MarcusMüller wrong format ?

Comment: yeah. 300 columns indicates data that doesn't really benefit from being in a plaintext comma separated value file (you're not going to be able to read it, anyway, as human). And 5GB says that this is actually impossible to handle efficiently programmatically, at a scale where it matters even on modern machines. Simply using a different storage format would save a lot of space, time, and it would include the column name information in itself. E.g. `sqlite3`, HDF5.

Comment: why are you adding a semicolon delimited header to a CSV (comma separated value) file, apart from the name "row" you chosen for the _columns_? your file is rotated 90°?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `sed`, I'd generate a file with your header:

```
printf 'row-%s\n' {0..299} | paste -sd';' > header
```

Then you can easily `cat`:

```
cat header file.csv
```

If you want to overwrite:

```
cat header file.csv > file.csv.tmp && mv file.csv.tmp file.csv
```

Or without intermediate file:

```
cat <(printf 'row-%s\n' {0..299} | paste -sd';') file.csv > file.csv.tmp && mv file.csv.tmp file.csv
```